# Must an object's ctor and dtor be on the same thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, raii

With C++ RAII, the dtor gets called when the object goes out of scope. The mechanisms for multithreading always involve passing a callback to be run on a new thread. Thus, I don't think it's possible for an object to be constructed in one thread and destructed in another, since those would have to be different scopes.

Am I right about this? Or are there some cases where an objects ctor and dtor can be called in different threads?

Comment: Objects with non-automatic storage duration? You do realize scope and object lifetime are independent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Thus, I don't think it's possible for an object to be constructed in one thread and destructed in another, since those would have to be different scopes.
>
> Am I right about this?

No. These functions can be called completely independent of any threading.

> Or are there some cases where an objects ctor and dtor can be called in different threads?

Sure there are cases (just daily bread and butter). Think about a simple producer / consumer model and message instances exchanged between threads through a queue.

The producer thread creates the message instance and pushes it into the queue. The consumer takes it off from the queue and the messages destructor will be called after it was processed.

Comment: Good example. Another, possibly more on-target, would be a dynamic allocation wrapped in a smart pointer.

Comment: @user4581301 Well, if the queue contains `std::unique_ptr`'s, that's an implementation detail, but yes (I would probably do it like this)..

Comment: Yes, you are right. Now that I think of it, another example is a unique_ptr being passed by move into a thread callback.

Comment: @Arcinde I'm pretty sure there are many more _real life_ examples ;-)

Comment: Wasn't talking about a queue. I was after a more generalized RAII case where there is a resource wrapped in an object with a guaranteed scope. @Arcinde reached the same conclusion, so all is good.

Answer (score 3):

> The mechanisms for multithreading always involve passing a callback to be run on a new thread.

False. There's plenty of cases where you just need another thread to do stuff or manage something in the background but don't care about the status. Additionally, there are other signalling methods besides callbacks (just one example would be [conditional variables](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable)).

Side note: a callback could be called on any thread, including the thread that you passed the callback to. It all depends on how you design the system. You don't have to make a new thread every time you invoke a callback (although that's one way to do it).

> Thus, I don't think it's possible for an object to be constructed in one thread and destructed in another, since those would have to be different scopes.

False. [Shared pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) allow pointers to objects to be passed around threads and once all references to the object are removed, then the object is destructed.

An example would be a networking thread that constructs an object to represent some message received from the network. That thread then puts that object on a shared queue and some other processing thread processes that message. Once the processing thread has completed, it can destruct the object and free the resources for other things.